# TableView within NavigationBar within TabBar Navigation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, tableview, tabbar

I am building an app with several levels.

- First level are the Tabs on the bottom of the screen. (MainWindow)
- Second Level is the content displayed with each tab in a TableView (Locations)
- Third Level is the detailed overview of the selected item in the Second level content. (LocationDetails)

First and Second levels work fine. Now I want to create the content of the detailled overview. I have created a new NIB called LocationDetails.xib. It only contains some static text (an inserted Text View). So I can view the loaded window.

In the Locations.m file I have the following function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString * locationCity = [[locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"];

NSLog(@"Your choice is: %@", locationCity);
```

Within this function I want to go to an other view (LocationDetails). What is the best way to go. If I haven't given you enough information, tell me! I can provide all the information you need!

Hope to hear from you soon!

With kind regards,

Douwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a navigation controller.

In your main xib file you would end up with something like this :

```
UITabBarViewController // Main Window
  tab 1:
    UINavigationController
      UITableView // (Locations)

  tab 2:
    UINavigationController
      UITableView // (Locations)
```

Then, the code to slide on your LocatonDetails is simple :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LocationDetailsViewController = [[LocationDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationDetails" bundle:nil];
    controller setLocation:[locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

Comment: hi Dean,Thanks for your quick reply. Does this mean that my Base Window (MainWindow) is a TabBar Window, my second window is a NavigationBased window with a TableView Within the vie of the Navigation Window?

Comment: Wait - you should only ever have one UIWindow in an iPhone app.  I think this tutorial should explain what I mean : http://b00gizm.posterous.com/how-to-embed-a-navigation-controller-inside-a

Comment: Hi Dean! Thnx Again!! I will follow this Tutorial!! I will come back here to reply this post, okay? Thnx for your reply!!!